# What is wrong about this Java code (simple CardLayout program)?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe, jlabel, cardlayout

http://pastie.org/4372510 - Click this link for the code. (Didnt post it here to keep question clean)

I was recently trying to create a simple Java program in order to learn cardLayout.
I wanted this program to show a JLabel saying "Label1" in the beginning.
When the user clicks the label, I wanted to switch cards. i.e show Label2.

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at potpie.changeLabel(potpie.java:34)"
```

This is the error that I am getting. It says something is wrong with the line 50 in the code I have pasted.

I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Looks pretty clear that at least one of `layout` or `cards` is null.

Comment: Forgive me, but do you have a constructor for potpie?

Comment: Your "changeLabel" method is called for a *new* potpie instead of the one that is displayed.

Comment: PaulTomblin is right - `layout` and `cards` are *both* null, because they haven't been initialized in the one created on line 84.

Comment: @AnkurSharma The simplest way to put it is that instead of changing the label of the potpie, you're creating a new one, changing the label of *that* one, then discarding the thing you just changed.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, I understand what the problem is! but how can i use the potpie object that i created in my main method for other classes. is that even possible?

Comment: You're going to have to do a lot of restructuring, but it's definitely *possible*. You'll have to make your `potpie` a field and make functions to return it. (I suppose after making it a field, you can reference it directly, but that's generally bad coding practice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        potpie ccObj = new potpie();
        ccObj.changeLabel();
    }
```

Is calling changeLabel on a *new* potpie (I hate your class names and method names, by the way, they are meaningless), not on the one that was instantiated (with a call to .koko) in main.

Comment: hello, yes I think you are right that I should use the same object that I used to call .koko() but how can i use that object in other classes. I created it in main only.

Comment: Make the jFrame responsible for switching cards, not one of the panels within the card layout.

Comment: @ Paul Tomblin But I cant do that in my specific case. Label1 should stimulate like a play button in a games main menu.